# Android Secret code- usage statistics

Tags: android, android-intent, secret-key

Is there any intent or method to get the values which show in the usage statistics? We can get that manually by dialing secret code *#*#4636#*#*

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            in.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.UsageStats");
            startActivity(in);
```

This will shows the UsageStatitics Activity. But i need to show in my application not in the default..

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: i need to get the usage time and count of the applications

Comment: ok i've written an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it requires being a system app. Also, since it's very hack-y, it might not work on some devices. Anyway, here it is:

http://jhshi.me/2014/04/02/get-package-usage-statistics-in-android/

or:

http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1816323/